# Controlled repetition of an animation using simulation nodes

Tags: simulation-nodes

I have this animation where I shoot out a bunch of points in a half-circle using simulation nodes. Is there any way to have this animation repeat itself every x seconds, using maybe a value or switch node to control when?

I've tried using a scene time + a wrap node and joining the geometry inside the simulation zone but this doesn't get me the amount of control over when to repeat the animation that I'm looking for.

[image]